# Enums with constructors and using it in switch JAVA

Tags: java, android, enums, switch-statement

I have enum, for example:

```
public enum Type {
    Type1(10),
    Type2(25),
    Type3(110);

    private final int value;

    Type(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And I want to use it enum in switch:

```
switch (indexSector) {
    case Type.Type2.getValue():
    //...
    break;
}
```

but IDE says "Constant expression required". How can I use Enum this type in switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an enum in a switch, but your cases must be the items of the enum themselves, not a method return value.

```
Type x = ...

switch (x) {
    case Type1: ...
       break;
    case Type2: ...
       break;
    case Type3: ...
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Type indexSector = ...;
int value = indexSector.getValue();
switch (indexSector) {
    case Type2:
        // you can use the int from the value variable
        //...
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I get it. It's works, but without "Type.Type2:", only "Type2:".

Answer (score 0):

```
Type indexType = ...
switch (indexType) {
    case Type.Type1:
    //...
    break;
    case Type.Type2:
        int indexValue = indexType.getValue();
    //...
    break;
    case Type.Type3:
    //...
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `new` on an enum.

Comment: No, actually you can't. At the article you provided they don't create enum instance using new keyword - they create an instance of a wrapper class called EnumTest. Ofc, enums can have constructors, but still the instances can't be instantiated using new.